# "flutter channel stable" failed in docker image: cirrusci when publish pages to gitlab

Tags: flutter, deployment, gitlab

I'm trying to publish my flutter page on gitlab which is the git host of my project. I'm using the ci configure like the following(from this [post](https://alexandergottlieb.com/2020/09/25/how-to-deploy-a-flutter-web-app-on-gitlab-pages-for-free/))

gitlab page CI configure

```
image: cirrusci/flutter:latest

before_script:
  - flutter channel stable
  - flutter upgrade
  - flutter config --enable-web
  - flutter pub get

pages:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - flutter build web
    - cp -r build/web public
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - public
  only:
    - live
```

The ci job failed in an error like:

```
...
$ flutter channel stable
Switching to flutter channel 'stable'...
git: fatal: 'origin/stable' is not a commit and a branch 'stable' cannot be created from it
Switching channels failed with error code 128.
...
```

What's the problem?

One thing worth to note is my flutter project locate in a subdirectory(ie., `my-flutter-dir`) of the repository root. Is it the reason? How to configure the CI script in this situation?

I've tried to add a `cd my-flutter-dir` as the first command in the `before_script`, but it still result in the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's turn out being an issue of the docker image. After I removed the `flutter channel` and `flutter upgrade` command in the `befor_script` part, everything is ok now.

Note if you have the flutter project in a subdirectory under the repository root, still you need to add `cd you-flutter-dir` command in the `before_script`. Also don't forget to put the `.gitlab-ci.yml` file in the root of the repository.